# How to get data from a website using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to fetch data from a svg element(graph). iam using x path with name() functionality but still it is returning empty strings.. my code from python was

```
outer_html_1 = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='nvd3-svg']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='nvd3 nv-wrap nv-lineChart']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='nv-focus']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='nvd3 nv-wrap nv-line']//*[local-name()='g']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='nv-groups']//*[local-name()='g' and @class='nv-group nv-series-2']//*[local-name()='path' and @class='nv-line']")
 print(outer_html_1)
```

let me know if i am missing any thing...
i want to answers

1. how to retrive the data in "d" element in the path class(highlitd)
2. by writing the python code entire tag is getting highlited i want only the values with "d"
   im quite new to html and python please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the element and print the text value ( unless it is hidden behind a iframe).

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


data = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//g/path[@class='nv-line']")))
print(data.get_attribute("d"))

# This should print the value from the attribute "d"
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//g/path[@class='nv-line']"}
E         (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121) getting this error... as there are multiple values does it become a list for the value d?

Comment: I added a explicit wait. if that does not work means, then we have to re look at the html source to see if there is any change.  The xpath targets only the first element in the DOM. if you need multiples, then you have to use findelements method which returns a list. Later you can just iterate through the loop to retireve what you need.

Comment: 1)//g/path[@class='nv-line'] ] when i search in inspect page this is not getting highlited.. //*[name()='path' and @class='nv-line' when i search with this it is getting highlited what do i use 2)how do i know if it is hidden in iframe 3) i tried the same with explicit wait functionality for 30,60 secs still i m getting unabletofindelement error

Comment: previously i have searched with find_elements_by_xpath  where when executed it is returning an empty string instead of some data...

Comment: Can you share the complete html source or the puplic url of the page.

Comment: the entire class is defiend in an i frame... i got it checked.. can you tell me how to access the elements in an iframe

Comment: Thanks for the response switch to iframe solution has worked for me i could see the data